# Server log shows normal activities OR Server logs show normal activities?

Tags: grammar

Where I am trying to collectively refer to server logs, should I say...

> Server log shows normal activities

or

> Server logs show normal activities

Comment: Are you referring to multiple logs, or just one log?

Answer (score 3):

If you're referring to multiple logs showing the same normal activities, you should say:

> The server logs show normal activity

or

> The server logs show the same normal activity

Note that in computing terms, normal activity can be application (and therefore log) specific. The second example shows that several logs show the same result. Whereas the first example shows that several logs might show the same result, but they are all normal.